# golang timestamp in RFC3339 format

Tags: go

how do we convert time.now() in time.Time( RFC3339) format?

Eg:

var t time.Time

timeNow= time.Now()

I want to assign timeNow to t

Comment: "I want to assign timeNow to t" - `t = timeNow` will do that ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-udYpId3QX9)). However, I doubt that answers your question so it might be worth rephrasing it if the answer below does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Golang has support for [various time formats](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    r := t.Format(time.RFC3339)

    fmt.Println("time.Now() ", t)
    fmt.Println("RFC3339 ", r)

}
```